# calculate accuracy and precision of confusion matrix

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, confusion-matrix

Is there any tool / R package available to calculate accuracy and precision of a confusion matrix?

The formula and data structure are [here](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/%7Edbd/cs831/notes/confusion_matrix/confusion_matrix.html).

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619853/r-how-to-make-a-confusion-matrix-for-a-predictive-model

Comment: That thread talks about creating confusion matrix. My question is to calculate accuracy and precision on top of a confusion matrix.

Comment: I found a R package which helps to do this. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/caret.pdf

Answer (score 34):

yes, you can calculate Accuracy and precision in R with [confusion matrix](http://www.inside-r.org/node/86995).  It uses [Caret package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/caret.pdf).

Here is the example :

```
lvs <- c("normal", "abnormal")
truth <- factor(rep(lvs, times = c(86, 258)),
                levels = rev(lvs))
pred <- factor(
               c(
                 rep(lvs, times = c(54, 32)),
                 rep(lvs, times = c(27, 231))),               
               levels = rev(lvs))

xtab <- table(pred, truth)
# load Caret package for computing Confusion matrix
library(caret) 
confusionMatrix(xtab)
```

And **Confusion Matrix for xtab** would be like this :

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          truth
pred       abnormal normal
  abnormal      231     32
  normal         27     54

               Accuracy : 0.8285
                 95% CI : (0.7844, 0.8668)
    No Information Rate : 0.75
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.0003097

                  Kappa : 0.5336
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.6025370

            Sensitivity : 0.8953
            Specificity : 0.6279
         Pos Pred Value : 0.8783
         Neg Pred Value : 0.6667
             Prevalence : 0.7500
         Detection Rate : 0.6715
   Detection Prevalence : 0.7645

       'Positive' Class : abnormal
```

So here is everything, that you want.

Comment: how to programatically  find precision and recall after results of confusionMatrix(xtab) are got?

Comment: Thanks Nishu. Just one extra information I want to add. confusionMatrix(xtab) has dependency on "e1071" package, so installation of this package may be required.

Comment: @Rupesh: yeah, that's required.

Answer (score 14):

@Harsh Trivedi

**byClass** allows you to pull out the *precision* and *recall* from the summary.  PPV is precision.  Sensitivity is recall. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall

```
library(caret)

result <- confusionMatrix(prediction, truth)
precision <- result$byClass['Pos Pred Value']    
recall <- result$byClass['Sensitivity']
```

I imagine you want to pull out the precision and recall to calculate the *f-measure* so here it goes.

```
f_measure <- 2 * ((precision * recall) / (precision + recall))
```

I also found this handy online calculator for sanity check.  http://www.marcovanetti.com/pages/cfmatrix/?noc=2

-bg

Comment: No need to calculate this yourself, just use `confusionMatrix(..., mode = "everything")`, please see below answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody is having the same issue as I did, the method `confusionMatrix()` in `caret` does indeed give sensitivity/specificity. **However**, if it is fed an object of type `train` it will run a different method, `confusionMatrix.train()` which does **not** have this information.

The solution is to feed the `data` and `reference` manually from the `train` object (i.e. `$pred$pred$` and `$pred$obs` respectively) to the `confusionMatrix()` method.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is looking: thanks to BGA's answer above I got clearer on how to read the `confusionMatrix()` output and realized you can get the F-measure right out of the `result$ByClass` output as F1.

```
 result$byClass
         Sensitivity          Specificity       Pos Pred Value       Neg Pred Value 
           0.9337442            0.8130531            0.8776249            0.8952497 
           Precision               Recall                   F1           Prevalence 
           0.8776249            0.9337442            0.9048152            0.5894641 
      Detection Rate Detection Prevalence    Balanced Accuracy 
           0.5504087            0.6271571            0.8733987
```

Calculating `f_measure` below with same formula as in above comment also gives 0.9048152.

You can also get the Accuracy from `results$overall`

```
result$overall
      Accuracy          Kappa  AccuracyLower  AccuracyUpper   AccuracyNull AccuracyPValue 
  8.841962e-01   7.573509e-01   8.743763e-01   8.935033e-01   5.894641e-01   0.000000e+00 
 McnemarPValue 
  2.745521e-13
```

Or use Balanced Accuracy from `results`

Answer (score 0):

Much more convenient than calculating the F1 score yourself, or to use `result$byClass`, you can just use **the `mode` argument in `confusionMatrix`** to print the F1 score, recall, and precision as well.

The default is `confusionMatrix(..., mode = "sens_spec")`, which shows the sensitivity and specificity. To show the F1 score, recall, and precision, using `mode = "prec_recall"`. To show all of them, use `mode = "everything"`:

```r
library(caret)

x <- matrix(c(231, 27, 32, 54), nrow = 2)
x
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]  231   32
#> [2,]   27   54

confusionMatrix(x, mode = "everything")
#> Confusion Matrix and Statistics
#> 
#>     A   B
#> A 231  32
#> B  27  54
#> 
#>                Accuracy : 0.8285
#>                  95% CI : (0.7844, 0.8668)
#>     No Information Rate : 0.75
#>     P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.0003097
#> 
#>                   Kappa : 0.5336
#> 
#>  Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.6025370
#> 
#>             Sensitivity : 0.8953
#>             Specificity : 0.6279
#>          Pos Pred Value : 0.8783
#>          Neg Pred Value : 0.6667
#>               Precision : 0.8783
#>                  Recall : 0.8953
#>                      F1 : 0.8868
#>              Prevalence : 0.7500
#>          Detection Rate : 0.6715
#>    Detection Prevalence : 0.7645
#>       Balanced Accuracy : 0.7616
#> 
#>        'Positive' Class : A
```