# How to construct the confusion matrix for a multi class variable

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

Suppose I have a factor variable `y` with n levels, for which I have both predictions and real outcomes available. How can I construct the confusion matrix?

```
set.seed(12345)
y_actual = as.factor(sample(c('A','B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), 100, replace = TRUE))
set.seed(12346)
y_predict = as.factor(sample(c('A','B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), 100, replace = TRUE))
```

This question is already answered for the case n = 2. See

[R: how to make a confusion matrix for a predictive model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619853/r-how-to-make-a-confusion-matrix-for-a-predictive-model)

**What I tried**

This is how far I got

```
ones = data.frame(total = rep(1,100));
confusion = aggregate(ones, list(Prediction = predict, Reality = real), sum, a.action=0)
confusion

  Prediction Reality total
1          A       A    12
2          B       A     5
3          C       A    15
4          A       B    15
5          B       B     7
6          C       B     8
7          A       C    12
8          B       C    16
9          C       C    10
```

Now this has to be brought in the shape of a matrix.

**Background**

The confusion matrix has as the horizontal label "actual class" and as vertical label "predicted class". The matrix elements are simply counts like this:

element (1,1) = Number of counts for actual class is A and predicted class is A

element (1,2) = Number of counts for actual class is A and predicted class is B

etc

Comment: `table(y_actual, y_predict)`?

Comment: @AnandaMahto yes, that works perfect. Why don't you answer this question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want with `table`:

```
table(y_actual, y_predict)
#         y_predict
# y_actual A B C D E
#        A 4 3 4 2 8
#        B 7 1 3 6 2
#        C 3 7 1 0 4
#        D 3 6 6 4 6
#        E 6 5 5 1 3
```

Answer (score 9):

Simply use `confusionMatrix` from the package caret

```
require(caret)
confusionMatrix(y_actual, y_predict)



          Reference
Prediction  A  B  C
         A 12  5 15
         B 15  7  8
         C 12 16 10
```